# DS3231 OSF register changing without lost date

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, battery, rtc

Dears, I have an logger prototype with arduino and [ds3231 breadboard](https://protosupplies.com/product/ds3231-rtc-with-eeprom-module/). My code check periodically OSF register to check if oscillator is/was stopped, as informed in [datasheet](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/real-time-clocks/DS3231.html). I turn on my logger, setting up date/hour, turn of and after some time, turn it on again to check if it's ok.

After that, the logger stay tuned off for a month. When I turned it on after this time, I note that OSF bit was changed, indicating that oscillator was stopped, but the data/time wasn't lost. I don't found possible process that can change the OSF bit in datasheet and [Maxim recommendation](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/504). Maybe a negative voltage on VCC that force battery go to bellow threshold can changes the OSF bit (Maxim recommendation and this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242169/rtc-battery-voltage-error-non-ideal-op-amp-error)).

Then, I test my logger connecting and disconnecting voltage (VCC) and checking the OSF bit, to simulate this possible begative voltage and not have problem with it.

My question is:

- why the OSF bit changed, indicating lost of battery and consequently lost of date/time, and not lost date/time in my logger;
- what could have happened with my turned off logger to change OSF bit and not lost date;

I'm using [Adafruid RTCLib](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib). Follow the simple code to check OSF bit:

```c
#include <Wire.h>
#include <RTClib.h>

RTC_DS3231 rtc;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rtc.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  if(rtc.lostPower())
  {
     Serial.println("Date lost");
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: excuse me @jsotola. I edited post to make myself clear. My question is why/how OSF bit changed, indicating lost of battery and data, and not lost data in my case (battery is ok)

Comment: How full is the battery? Is it a rechargable or not? The product page is a bit contradicting. As the schematic shows a crude charging circuit, while the photo and schematic show the use of a **non**-rechargeable CR2032. Is the resistor removed like shown in the second product picture?

Comment: The battery is a CR2032 non rechargeable and new (3.11V). I didn't remove resistor for this test, but I will. The question is that the OSF bit, for lost battery, change while the system was turned off for a month, only with CR2032 for keeping date/time. I'm using a Chinese breadboard as link in post.

Comment: the breadboard have a diode in positive of battery, then negative voltage will not affect battery.